# How to use xymatrix with a0poster?

Tags: xy-pic, a0poster

I want to make a DIN-A0 poster using the documentclass `a0poster`. Why can't I draw diagrams in that documentclass? The MWE below crashes and I don't know how to fix that. :(

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amscd, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\xymatrix{A & B}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is unrelated to the class used.

Comment: Sorry. I made my minimal working example a little too minimal. :/ My problem is related to the class and therefore my problem is something else. ;) I will investigate it more precisely and eventually post another question.